# What would have been the correct Setup for a server that died?

Tags: active-directory, backup

I work at a real estate office that has 30 work stations. The IT guy who cant be reached when you really need him had setup Active Directory with a file server for the stations.  About 3 days ago the the one server in the basement died. The boss has been yelling at him and from what I hear there was no backup. The total amount of people who used AD out of the 30 stations was 8. The rest are just real estate agents who surf the net. Was AD really necessary? Was their a way to mirror the OS so this would not have happened? I'm asking cause I'm curious and really thinking of entering the IT field.

Comment: There are so many things wrongs here. 1) Backups. Always. 2) Yes really, olways and off-site.  3) At least two AD controllers.  4) Lack of documentation.  5) Only 30 workstations and a full time IT'er? Either your organision is rich, or maybe it is someone who also has other tasks (in which case the usually option is to hire a third party to do 'The IT stuff' for you).  6) Mirroring is nice, but without backups it is not enough. 7... Getting long for a comment, byut I am sure I could add several more points.

Comment: `The total amount of people who used AD out of the 30 stations was 8.`  That's... really not accurate either.  AD allows central management and AAA (authentication, authorization, access) of all the workstations and users.  In any event, there's just too much wrong here to address.  [Literally, books have been written about how to sysadmin.](http://www.amazon.com/Practice-System-Network-Administration-Edition/dp/0321492668)

Comment: I can't comment about whether or not the IT guy did his due diligence in "covering all of the bases" (and it doesn't sound like he did) but before we all rush to condemnation I'd like to say that I have seen many clients that refuse to implement many things we would consider best practice (multiple DC's, backups, etc.) because they don't want to spend the money to implement a proper infrastructure. I advise them of the risks and leave them to their own devices. It may be the case that the IT guy here did the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD is necessary in order to easily handle centralized authentication for all your stations. Typically in your case, you have a file server and you want to setup permissions on shared folder, that's the right way to do, use n Active Directory server and manage users, groups and permission on it.

About the mirroring, Active Directory is really easy to duplicate as it allows server replication, either in write or read mode. The best solution for you would have been to setup  two physical server (do virtualization to simplify the management and for better scalability) and install two active directory with replication services. A documentation can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961788.aspx)

Backup are always necessary, both on-site and off-site. We can also develop the subject if you want but I agree with the two comments, sysadmin is a job and a simple topic can't develop the entire subject.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as a new guy I really appreciate it